# Creating a pie chart with historical motion in Rstudio

Tags: r, bigdata, visualization, rstudio

So, I created several pie charts showing voting percentages for republicans and democrats, from 2008 to 2016 with plotly package in Rstudio. What I would like to do, to make it sleek, is create a menu for a user to click on(2008, 2012, 2016), and the pie chart would motion into the correct vote totals. Would I need to create a shiny app to do this?

Comment: with R that's probably the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Shiny App, will be the place to display the graphics, however the animation you are looking for is not something that `plotly` would create, to the best of my knowledge.

`d3` however is a different beast. It can create aesthetically pleasing graphics. For your specific case, here is the example

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410

Or you can look at the entire [gallery](https://d3js.org/)